# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes (Angular8)

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular8, angular-routing

I maked my angular-app. All good works. But for deploy to server I getting error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'myUrl/app.aspx'

After build prod my app doesn't work either (I set base href and all files load, but I getting warning **Unhandled Navigation Error**).

I make difficult routing for my app.
I using submodules for routing. And I think the problem related with **APP_BASE_HREF** or wrong routing for my app/submodules.

My example:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NbThemeModule, NbLayoutModule, NbSidebarModule, NbButtonModule, NbTabsetModule, NbCardModule } from '@nebular/theme';
import { NbEvaIconsModule } from '@nebular/eva-icons';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainModule } from './components/main/main.module';
import { AddModule } from './components/add/add.module';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
    NbLayoutModule,
    NbEvaIconsModule,
    NbSidebarModule.forRoot(),
    NbButtonModule,
    NbTabsetModule,
    NbCardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MainModule,
    AddModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't have **providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]** and all good works. But for deploy I geted error message:

> Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or add a base
>   element to the document.

I add **APP_BASE_HREF** and error disappeared.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './components/main/main.module#MainModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'event',
    loadChildren: './components/event/event.module#EventModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    loadChildren: './components/add/add.module#AddModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'archive',
    loadChildren: './components/archive/archive.module#ArchiveModule'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**main-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewEventsComponent } from './view-events/view-events.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ViewEventsComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

**event-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { EventPageComponent } from './event-page/event-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: ':id',
        component: EventPageComponent,
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class EventRoutingModule { }
```

And I noticed:

after build app - generated files of module: archive and event, but don't generated file for main-module.

Comment: is there `<base href="/">` in index.html ?

Comment: I think you don't have it

Comment: I tried use <base href="/"> , but this don't work for me

Comment: did you use `ng build --prod` ?

Comment: Yes, I use ng build --prod for deploy

Comment: it seems you are using IIS. error might be in web.config url rewriting. Maybe not

Comment: Yep, I using IIS. Noew I have problem with path for submodules: `Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk components-archive-archive-module failed.` . Path for submodules files is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with fixed in **app-routing.module.ts**. A added  *{ useHash: true }*:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```